# Replace Python conditionals with a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How you can solve the following by applying dictionaries in Python 
The idea is to remove the if and replace it with a dictionary and get the same result.

```
def apply_fun(row,col='a'):
    if row[col] <= 5:
        val = 5
    elif row[col] <= 10:
        val = 10
    elif row[col] <= 15:
        val = 15
    elif row[col] <= 20:
        val = 20
    elif row[col] <= 25:
        val = 25        
    else:
        val = 30
    return val

values = [[12,2],[3,2],[23,2],[7,2],[19,2]]

db = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['a','b'])

db['new'] = db.apply(apply_fun, axis=1)

    a   b   new
0   12  2   15
1   3   2   5
2   23  2   25
3   7   2   10
4   19  2   20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are rounding to nearest multiples of 5, Use:

```
import numpy as np

db["new"] =  np.ceil(db["a"] / 5).astype(int) * 5
print(db)
```

This prints:

```
    a  b  new
0  12  2   15
1   3  2    5
2  23  2   25
3   7  2   10
4  19  2   20
```

Comment: Because of the flexibility of the solution and because it is replicable not only in fixed scales of 5 or 10, excellent response

Answer (score 1):

You're just rounding the numbers up to nearest 5s.  You can do this instead:

```
db['new'] = db['a'].add(4).floordiv(5).mul(5)

    a   b   new
0   12  2   15
1   3   2   5
2   23  2   25
3   7   2   10
4   19  2   20
```

If however you are talking about checking a dictionary for range then it's not feasible, since dictionary are mapped one to one.  Unless you want to start identifying `{1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this with a dictionary. When ordering is important, use a list.

```
def apply_fun(row,col='a'):
    limits = [5, 12, 15, 18, 25, 30]
    for i in limits:
        if row[col] <= i:
            return i
    return limits[-1] # default to the last item
```

Note that this should only be used if there isn't a simple mathematical solution as in the other answers.